# Turn href into variant selector - Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am struggling to convert my `select` variants into a button format. The various options are displayed as using `select` however I am attempting to change them into image blocks and have them selectable.

I have an output of my variants as buttons/hrefs but I'm not sure how to change the variant selector to make them functional as it currently does in the `select` dropdown. I think its something like this which is the themes current jQuery selection call.

**Existing working Select variants**

```
<select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name="id" {% if product.variants.size == 1 %}class="single-option-selector"{% endif %}>
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
            <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
</select>
```

```
     $(function() {    
              $product = $('#product-' + {{ product.id }});

              new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select-{{ product.id }}", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback{% if product-form == 'product' %}, enableHistoryState: true{% endif %} });          

            });
```

**The href output I have created which I need to be made into a variant selector.**

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}

     <div class="one-third column alpha thumbnail basket-select" onclick="myFunction()">

      <div class="info"> 

          <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0924/5464/{{ variant.image }}">

          <span class="title"> {{ variant.title }}</span> 
          <span class="price">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>

      <div class="quick_shop action_button" style="display: none;">Select Box</div>
      </div>

     </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

I have tried creating a seperate jQuery method but failed to get it working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching the select boxes over to radio buttons using an updated version of option_selection.js. I then styled them appropriately

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/shopify/option_selection.js?e90f577220d8b5f6b4fa5679a9ae14e9a536abf5

Comment: You did not specify radio buttons so I guess I missed that. Good on you for figuring out the switch though.

Answer (score 1):

1. do not use option-selector code. it is useless for this exercise
2. grab a copy of the product using the Liquid JSON filter
3. go through the product options and variants yourself and build your buttons.

Now you have replaced all your problems with the above code with a clean, workable solution of buttons per available variant.